# reformatting JSON data - missing array

Tags: javascript, json

I am very new to web scraping and we stumbled across this JSON data.

I am confused to see the data come through this way.

```
{"XYZ": {
    "PromoURL": "null",
    "Z_WEEE": 0,
    "isACD": "false",
    "ProductCode": "3195",
    "ProductStatus": "Y5",
    "ListPrice": "%24885.00",
    "CurrencyCode": "$"
}
"YYZ": {
    "PromoURL": "null",
    "Z_WEEE": 0,
    "isACD": "false",
    "ProductCode": "3195",
    "ProductStatus": "Y5",
    "ListPrice": "%24225.00",
    "CurrencyCode": "$",
}
```

Is it possible to reformat so that the "XYZ" and "YYZ" is an object SKU:
and make it look like this?

```
"productList": [
    {
    "SKU": "XYZ",
    "PromoURL": "null",
    "Z_WEEE": 0,
    "isACD": "false",
    "ProductCode": "3195",
    "ProductStatus": "Y5",
    "ListPrice": "%24885.00",
    "CurrencyCode": "$"
    },
    {
    "SKU": "YYZ",
    "PromoURL": "null",
    "Z_WEEE": 0,
    "isACD": "false",
    "ProductCode": "3195",
    "ProductStatus": "Y5",
    "ListPrice": "%24225.00",
    "CurrencyCode": "$"
    }
    ]
```

I have tried looking up how to reformat but nothing is helpful! Please help!

Comment: What specific issue are you having? It looks like you need to iterate over the object keys and build up an array of the keys' values with the additional property.

Comment: I have about a 1000+ entries with different SKU (XYZ,YYZ,etc) 
I tried let obj = "XYZ": {
    "PromoURL": "null",
    "Z_WEEE": 0,
    "isACD": "false",
    "ProductCode": "3195",
    "ProductStatus": "Y5",
    "ListPrice": "%24885.00",
    "CurrencyCode": "$"
} 
obj.XYZ = [obj.XYZ] but I'm not too sure how to create the productList array and insert the object

Comment: what language do you use?

let example = objects.map(function() {

})

Comment: I'm trying to create a loop to reformat all of the JSON data in javascript thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  "XYZ": {
    "PromoURL": "null",
    "Z_WEEE": 0,
    "isACD": "false",
    "ProductCode": "3195",
    "ProductStatus": "Y5",
    "ListPrice": "%24885.00",
    "CurrencyCode": "$"
  },
  "ABC": {
    "PromoURL": "null",
    "Z_WEEE": 0,
    "isACD": "false",
    "ProductCode": "3195",
    "ProductStatus": "Y5",
    "ListPrice": "%24225.00",
    "CurrencyCode": "$",
  }
}

const productList = Array.from(
  Object.entries(obj),
  ([key, value]) => {
    return {
      SKU: key,
      ...value
    };
  }
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(productList, null, 2));
```

`obj` and `productList` are both javascript objects so you need to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to convert to and from a JSON string.

Comment: @AndrewLee I'm not sure what you're asking--this code doesn't specify the object. What does your **actual** data look like?